# Flash Builder 4: Workspace launcher keeps prompting for a workspace

Tags: actionscript-3

I am on a MAC with two (2) user profiles.

When I launch Flash builder, I am getting a "workspace in user" message, and Flash Builder keeps prompting me to choose a workspace and it's pointing to the *other* user's profile.

I keep pointing it to my workspace under "my documents" and I check the following box:

```
Use this as the default and do not ask again.
```

However, every time I open up Flash builder, it's asking me again? Is there any way to stop this? Like, is there some file I have to delete or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it doesn't say "Workspace in *use*"?

If so, a restart should fix it, alteratively look it the Mac equivalent of task manager and you should find a hanging process for flash builder.